# HTTP error message from API not showing in Angular component

Tags: angular, http, error-handling

I have an ExpressJS backend endpoint that goes (figuratively) like this:

```
function myFunction(req, res, next) {
  if (someErrorCondition)
    res.status(400).json({message: "Something went wrong."});
  else {
    myBackendService.someFunc.then(res.status(200).json({message: "Success!"}))
     .catch(err => next(err))
  }
}
```

And from an Angular frontend component, I am requesting this endpoint through a Subscription:

```
this.myFrontendService.someFunc().subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res);
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

When the call runs correctly (i.e status 200), logs (as expected) the JSON object `{message: "Success!"}` as the `res` object. But when it fails, it logs:

```
Http failure response for http://localhost:4000/myRoute/myFunction: 400 Bad Request
```

And I am not getting anywhere the message "Something went wrong." that I sent from the backend. Are the error codes handled differently in Angular?

Also, when I call the backend endpoint using cURL, both messages are returned as JSON objects as expected.

EDIT: myFrontService class declaration looks like this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FrontendService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  someFunc() {
    return this.http.put(`localhost:4000/myRoute/myFunction`, {data: "here's some data"});
  }
}
```

Comment: what does this.myFrontendService.someFunc() look like?

Comment: @E.Maggini I edited the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was using an HttpInterceptor for the authentication process to filter and handle the 401 and 403 codes (related to permission errors), and then for all the rest of codes (as this 400 in the question), I just threw the **err.message** and not the **err.error.message**, where the former is the string I was getting in my question: '*Http failure response for...*', and the latter is the actual message sent from the backend: "*Something went wrong.*".

Here is the HttpInterceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
        if ([401, 403].indexOf(err.status) !== -1) {
            // auto logout if 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden response returned from api
            this.authService.logout();
            location.reload(true);
        }

        const errorFromBackend = err.error.message; // Something went wrong.
        const errorGeneric = err.message; // Http failure response for...
        return throwError(errorFromBackend);
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors can be of different kind (server error, network error). Have a look at the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#handling-request-errors)

You can create a method that's extract the error message based on the type.

**component.ts**

```
//...
this.myFrontendService.someFunc().subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res);
  },
  error => {
    this.handleError(error);
  });


private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) //client side error
  {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } 
  else  //server side error
  {
    //console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, body was: ${error.error}`);
    let resp = JSON.parse(error.error);
    console.log(resp.message);//Since you returned a {message: ...} object from API
  }
}
```

You can also add the handler directly in your service, like in the documentation link

Comment: I tried to use the code you provide, but when I uncomment the console.error() on the else condition, I get undefined on both the error.status and the error.error. Logging the error I get the same message from my question and since it's a string, JSON.parse() throws an error. Thank you for your response.